# Interrupt ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

How can I immediately stop a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and discard any pending operations when a script is interrupted, as in the example below:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


def get_parallel(arguments_list: list[dict]):
    try:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
            futures_buffer = [executor.submit(requests.get, **kwargs) for kwargs in arguments_list]

            for future in as_completed(futures_buffer):
                try:
                    response = future.result()
                    print (response.url)
                    yield response.url, response.status_code, response.json()['args']
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
                    yield 'KeyboardInterrupt 1'
                    return
                except Exception as exception:
                    yield exception
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        yield 'KeyboardInterrupt 2'
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = [dict(url=f'https://httpbin.org/get?q={i}') for i in range(200)]
    for t in get_parallel(arguments):
        print(t)
```

As the code is now, when I run it from terminal and then call ^C, it will stop printing results but will hang for the same time as if it wasn't interrupted, and finally it will print `KeyboardInterrupt 2`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown

Comment: @MichaelButscher - shutdown doesn't stop in-progress futures.

Comment: @tdelaney Right. If "immediately" really means that, my approach isn't enough.

Comment: Thank you, friends. Please see last paragraph added to my question in edit.

Comment: Feeling lucky? You could move to a process pool executor, and kill the pids in `executor._processes` to stop them immediately. This relies on a using a private variable and is a hack that could break in the future.

Comment: @tdelaney, thank you, I will study your answer to be as sure as possible that I understand what is happening.

Comment: might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72942970/627042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't signal individual threads in python and even if you could, there's no guarantee that requests didn't create its own threads as workers. You can kill processes, so you could delegate the request to a subprocess and kill it when you get a keyboard interrupt. The cleanest way to do this is to manage your own subprocesses and a queue of work items. But, if you don't mind a little hacking, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` keeps a list of its pool processes and you can hijack that. But its hacking ... it may break some time in the future.
Since the response is pickled and sent back to the parent process, its best to have an intermediate worker function that grabs useful data from the response object, rather than the response object itself.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os
import requests
import signal

def worker(arguments_list: dict):
    """use requests to get web page and return url, status, json args"""
    resp = requests.get(**arguments_list)
    # todo: when status_code not 200 and json decode fails, do...???
    return resp.url, resp.status_code, resp.json()['args']

def get_parallel(arguments_list: list[dict]):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
        try:
            futures_buffer = [executor.submit(worker, kwargs) for kwargs in arguments_list]

            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_buffer):
                    url, status_code, args = future.result()
                    print (url)
                    yield url, status_code, args
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for pid in executor._processes:
                os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            yield 'KeyboardInterrupt 2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = [dict(url=f'https://httpbin.org/get?q={i}') for i in range(200)]
    for t in get_parallel(arguments):
        print(t)
```

Comment: on ^C, it lagged for some time and then raised these:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in get_parallel
    print (url)
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    for t in get_parallel(arguments):
  File "test.py", line 23, in get_parallel
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGKILL'
```

Comment: I tested it on my linux machine and it quit immediately with "KeyboardInterrupt 2" as the last yielded item. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. It worked when I changed it to signal.SIGINT, is that the correct one?

Comment: Yes, SIGINT should be fine. Better, maybe. SIGKILL can't be caught.

Comment: I guess you should know your answer also works using `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)` instead of `for pid in executor._processes: os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @VBobCat - From the docs _If cancel_futures is True, this method will cancel all pending futures that the executor has not started running. Any futures that are completed or running won’t be cancelled_ I thought this whole exercise was to terminate futures that are in progress. shutdown doesn't do that.

Comment: Oh, I get the difference now. But the code I posted (even after my edit) wasn't doing even that. After ^C, my code lagged by the time needed to complete all the requests, that's what was bugging me the most.

Comment: @VBobCat - good point. This more extreme route is when you really want to cancel in progress - maybe the server is slow or maybe its even throttled you for too many downloads.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to stop earlier with a little baby sitting. The trick is to keep the main thread in a polling loop, using [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait), to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and cancel pending operations.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED

def get_parallel(arguments_list: list[dict]):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
        futures_buffer = [executor.submit(requests.get, **kwargs) for kwargs in arguments_list]

        not_done = futures_buffer
        try:
            while not_done:
                done, not_done = wait(not_done, timeout=1, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
                for future in done:
                    response = future.result()
                    print (response.url)
                    yield response.url, response.status_code, response.json()['args']

        # Cancel any futures not done on KeyboardInterrupt
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
            yield 'KeyboardInterrupt 1' # Or re-raise if not in generator
```